# How to set the sorting of given and family names of they author key when in citations and in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I use this:

```
% bib
\usepackage[style=verbose-note,pageref=true,dashed=false,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

to correctly set the sorting of given and family names in citations (footnotes). I want to reverse the order in the bibliography but I don't know how, any tips?

Comment: Mhhh, `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}` should only influence the output in the bibliography and not the output in citations. So maybe you just want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`? It would help greatly if you could extend your code into a (self-contained) compilable example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and show the current output and desired output in your question.

Comment: That did the trick even though I found the documentation a bit confusing, if you want to answer so I can close my question. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what exactly you are asking, but note that the `sortname` format generally only applies to bibliography entries.

In full citations `biblatex` actually sets `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`, which means that names that would normally show in `sortname` format (which defaults to `family-given/given-family`) show in `default` (which is `given-family`). So changes to `sortname` do generally not affect the citations.

From what you say so far maybe you want

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

---

I guess most of that can not really be found in the `biblatex` documentation, because this is a question about the behaviour of individual styles and not about core `biblatex`. For the most part the `biblatex` documentation only documents the `biblatex` core interface, style decisions are usually only mentioned in passing.

If you want to customise a style it is always useful to have the source code at hand and look at it directly.